# Get iTerm location Applescript

Tags: applescript

I would like to know how to get the current location of the current session in iTerm using Applescript.

I have tried all sorts of things. The dictionary is very difficult for me to understand.

Here is my latest attempt

```
tell application "iTerm"
        tell the current session of current terminal
            set theSelection to attachment file name
            display dialog theSelection
        end tell

    end tell
```

And the error this produces is:

```
error "iTerm got an error: Can’t get file name of current session of current terminal." number -1728 from file name of current session of current terminal
```

I just want the location the iTerm session is currently in: `/Users/SuperCoolGuy/Desktop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ugly...

```
tell application "iTerm"
    if not (exists terminal 1) then reopen
    set mySession to current terminal's current session
    tell mySession
        write text "pwd"
        set sessionContents to it's text
    end tell
end tell

set myPath to paragraph -2 of (do shell script "grep . <<< " & quoted form of sessionContents)
```

Comment: Indeed it is :) what does `grep . >>>` do? I know what grep itself does just never seen it like that

Comment: When I tested the script, contents (it's text) returns the text of the terminal followed by several trailing linefeeds. The grep command removes the line feeds to ensure the next to last paragraph returns the path and not a blank line.

Comment: Good ol hack +1, worked for me, had to put a delay 0.1 after the write though, as sometimes was contents was not being updated straight away.

Comment: It works I was just asking for you to explain it for my own knowledge. :) THANKS! Appreciate the help

Answer (score 3):

If somebody stumbles upon this question, there's another option now with [Shell integration](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html). With it you can access the path in AppleScript using the iTerm defined variable `session.path`:

```
activate application "iTerm"
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current session of current window
        set myTerm to (variable named "session.path")
        write text "echo this is the current path: " & myTerm
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

That information isn't currently available through iTerm's AppleScript interface. The only exposed properties of the session object having to do with what's running in it (as opposed to its visual appearance) are `contents` and `tty`, and those aren't what you're looking for here.

Comment: Could I run something like "pwd" and get the result back perhaps?

Comment: Only if you know the user is at a shell prompt. If they're running a text editor, for instance, typing "pwd" into the terminal won't do what you expect. Even if they are at a shell prompt, finding the output on screen will be complicated.

Comment: Tell me about it :) I thought this would be easy. I can garuntee they will be in either iTerm or Terminal. I get the `write text "pwd"` but how do I get that return value out?

Comment: You'd have to wait a moment for it to run, then search the `contents` of the session for the output. It's a messy, unreliable process; I'd avoid it if you can!